# Match string between two words in DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a DataFrame and one of the columns contains a text from which I want to extract some information.

I have two words: 'Type' and 'Capacity', between them is a string of numeric and non-numeric characters + white spaces are possible - I want to save that to a new column.

This is my code

```
df['new'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'Type (\w+) Capacity', x).group(1))
print (df['new'])
```

It doesn't give me errors, but prints out this:

> Series([], Name: test, dtype: object)

I don't understand what is wrong. Thanks for help

Comment: Looks like you just need `df['new'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'Type (\w+) Capacity')`. Well, with `expand=True` perhaps, and eventual `fillna('')` to avoid NaN values.

Comment: Maybe you also need to convert the values to string. Try `df['text'].astype(str)...` or `.apply(' '.join)` if there are arrays/lists.

Comment: '.str.extract', worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df['new'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'Type (\w+) Capacity')
```

The [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method will only return the captured values (those matched with parenthetical pattern parts).

You may also pass `expand=True` if you want to make sure a data frame only is returned (or `False` to get Series/Index/DataFrame), and if you have no matches on some rows, `.fillna('')` may be useful.